# Where does the name of i3 (the WM) come from?

Tags: history, i3

I was thinking about this, so I searched the i3 website, but did not find anything. I was alarmed by the thought, that the name was ie (internet explorer) in leetspeak. It might also be a weird emoticon. I would really like to know the real answer.

Comment: It might as well come from `wmii` on which `i3` is based - they just added one `i`.

Comment: Why not just [asking the developers](http://i3wm.org/contact/) instead?